# Creating a command within a list

Tags: macros, lists

So I'm trying to create a simplified kind of list inside of an environment, so that calling one command will create an enumerated item and calling another will create a subitem.

Here's my code:

```
\newcounter{usagenumber}
\newcommand\enumerate{\stepcounter{usagenumber}{\small \arabic{usagenumber}.}}
\newenvironment{usages}
{
   \setcounter{usagenumber}{0}
   \begin{description*}
   \newcommand\itemdef[1]{\item[\enumerate] #1}
   \newcommand\itemex[1]
   {
      \begin{description*}
         \item[$\cdot$] #1
      \end{description*}
   }
}
{
   \end{description*}
}
```

I'm using the mdwlist package for the modified asterisk list, just for spacing. Typeset with xelatex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can't use `\enumerate`, because it's already defined (for the `enumerate` environment).

Comment: When defining commands in the context of other macros/environments, one must use `##1`, instead of `#1`, one extra `#` for each level of command-within-a-command.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- "one extra `#`"? I thought you needed to double: `#1`, `##1`, `####1`, etc....

Comment: @jon You know?  I have never programmed at that depth until just now.  And you are correct I have discovered through testing.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- Me neither! (Hence the tentative 'thought'.)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of your full intent, but perhaps something like this.  As egreg pointed out in the comments, `enumerate` was already taken; and as I pointed out, the occurrences of `#1` in the definitions of `\itemdef` and `\itemex` had to be recast as `##1`, since they occurred in the context of environment `usages`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{usagenumber}
\newcommand\xenumerate{\stepcounter{usagenumber}{\small \arabic{usagenumber}.}}
\newenvironment{usages}
{
   \setcounter{usagenumber}{0}
   \begin{description}
   \newcommand\itemdef[1]{\item[\xenumerate] ##1}
   \newcommand\itemex[1]
   {
      \begin{description}
         \item[$\cdot$] ##1
      \end{description}
   }
}
{
   \end{description}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{usages}
\itemdef{define xxx}
\itemdef{define yyy}
\itemex{example of yyy}
\itemdef{define zzz}
\itemex{example of zzz}
\itemdef{define aaa}
\end{usages}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had misspelled enumerate in my document, so that wasn't the problem. But thank you, the ##1 fixed it. Sorry for being an idiot.